# Controller@method laravel not defined en la vista

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Laravel 8 o algún anterior cambió la forma en la que se llaman a las rutas ahora se llamarían así:

```
Route::get('formulario', [peliculaController::class, 'formulario']);
```

Bueno esto anda bien pero ahora cuando quiero ejecutar un metodo de un controlador para recibir los datos del formulario me salta este error:

```
InvalidArgumentException
Action peliculaController@recibir not defined.
```

Esto es lo que tengo en mi codigo de la vista

```
<form action="{{action( [peliculaController::class, 'recibir'] )}}" method="post">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text">
    <br><br>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Esto es lo que tengo en mi controlador

```
public function recibir(Request $request){
    $nombre = $request->input('nombre');
    $email = $request->input('email');
    var_dump($nombre);
    var_dump($email);

}
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme gracias

Comment: Esa es la sintaxis que dice en la documentación de laravel, si uso la otra no me funciona. Específicamente acá https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#defining-controllers

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el contenido de web.php o de tus rutas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno lo resolví haciendo esto pero no se si será la mejor manera, si alguien sabe como hacerlo se los marco como correcta

```
<form action="{{action('App\Http\Controllers\peliculaController@recibir')}}" method="post">
```

Answer (score 2):

Asumamos que tienes una ruta definida de la siguiente forma:

```
  Route::post('registra', [App\Http\Controllers\peliculaController::class, 'recibir']);
```

Entonces podemos darle un nombre a la misma para un manejo mas simple así:

```
  Route::post('registra', [App\Http\Controllers\peliculaController::class, 'recibir'])->name('registra-pelicula');
```

Para que al momento de que tratas de invocar dicha ruta en tu formulario lo hagas a través del name en el helper `route` y no de la URI directamente o como en este caso del nombre de la clase del controlador y del método asociado a esta, mas o menos así:

```
  <form action="{{ route('registra-pelicula') }}" method="post">
```

Comment: Action recibir-pelicula not defined. Hice exactamente lo que escribiste pero me sigue saliendo el not defined

Comment: Si te dice eso entonces puede que estés invocando a un controlador equivocado es decir que el que llamas no es donde está el método definido

Comment: Hola me funcionó poniendo la ruta completa pero no se si sería la forma correcta o la más rapida. Asi lo resolví. 
`<form action="{{action('App\Http\Controllers\peliculaController@recibir')}}" method="post">
` ¿Sabes si hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo en laravel 8?

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Te comento lo que ocurre en Laravel 8.

En web.php en las rutas tienes las siguientes opciones:

Opción 1(si te fijas tienes que añadir la url completa):

```
Route::get('formulario', [App\Http\Controllers\PeliculaController::class, 'formulario']);
```

Opción 2:

```
Route::get('formulario', 'App\Http\Controllers\PeliculaController@formulario')->name('formulario');
```

Mi Opción:
Creas una variable llamada ruta para no repetir en cada uno de los controladores:

```
$ruta = "App\Http\Controllers\\";
Route::get('formulario', $ruta.'PeliculaController@formulario')->name('formulario');
Route::post('recibir', $ruta.'PeliculaController@recibir')->name('recibir');
```

En el formulario:

```
<form name="formulario" method="POST" action="{{ route('recibir') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

En el controlador:

```
public function formulario()
{
    return view('pelicula.formulario');
}

public function recibir(Request $request)
{
    $nombre  = $request->input('nombre');
    var_dump($nombre);
}
```

Comment: Tu segunda opción debería dar error desde que te falta una comilla por aperturar

Comment: Cierto lo metí a mano xD, arreglado gracias. Si os a parecido bien mi respuesta os agradecería vuestra puntuación :)